# Tutorial for building a REST service in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, wcf, rest

I cannot figure out how to build a REST API web service for VB.NET.  I can't find any tutorials on the internet and the Microsoft templates only come in C#.

Anyone have any links that could help me out?

Comment: [You aren't the only one](http://forums.asp.net/t/1459402.aspx/1?WCF+Rest+Starter+Kit+in+Visual+Basic+)

Answer (score 9):

**Update**: ASP.NET Web API is now the best way of creating a REST service for .NET, there are plenty of tutorials online: http://www.asp.net/web-api

---

**Pre-ASP.NET Web API answer**: I also found there to be a lack of documentation on this. I mostly followed [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/RestServiceAPI.aspx) tutorial, which can be easily understood and thus implemented in VB.Net.

There are also quite a few decent templates of WCF REST (VB.Net) that can be downloaded via Online Templates in Visual Studio. You might want to look at *WCF REST Service Template 40(VB)*.

There's also the [WCF REST Starter Kit Preview 2](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24644) on Codeplex.